# Accessing sensitive api keys from react-native app

Tags: react-native, expo

There is an SDK that requires an API key to be accessed from the mobile app. This means I can't simply call the SDK from a lambda endpoint or serverless endpoint and send back the data.

What is a secure way to let mobile phone users access this API key without abusing it?

I believe storing the API key on the phone itself is a bad idea. My thought was to simply have the user hit an endpoint which gives them the key, but could that be tampered with somehow? Each user requires a JWT token to access the API endpoint (fyi).

Answer (score 1):

FYI *all client side app communications and App data should be considered "unsecure" from user access.*

- End users can listen to network requests via proxies or even other apps.
- Hardcoding on ios / android app will not protect you either. This is because you can decompile those apps (especially android) and/or inspect the Javascript bundle either from the local code or network request from the codepush bundle if applicable.

**Regarding client sdk api keys**:

- If the key is client facing and the app is publicly available, it should be considered a public key. If that's not the case there is something wrong with how that key is distributed or the target audience needs to be locked down to trusted users only (like how you are logging in and handing off keys, those users would need to be trusted with those keys)

**Recommendations**

1. Follow the guidelines related to authorization and token access for the specific api key. If it's a public key, many providers will allow for locking down the key so it can only be used on your specific app/domain.
2. Consider your target users. If they are authorized accounts then creating an authorization + key passing post authorization should be reasonable.
3. Consider making the key unique so you can track abuse. Ie each user gets a unique map key dynamically generated from that service. If it's your key, you can throttle access that way easily.
4. You could add some sort of encrypted storage such as [react-native-encrypted-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-encrypted-storage). After the user logs in, store that key given to the user post login, then rehydrate on app refresh. Most apps will not have access to your apps files, and with encrypted storage you can prevent easy access even if there is an app that can access your pap's folder.

Comment: Those are some good recommendations. I really appreciate your thorough response. Regarding #4, how would I pass the key initially once they login? Is it via a custom endpoint that gives API keys?